# MUX output amplitude level

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, multiplexer

I am using MUX 4051(8:1 Mux and 3 select lines) IC in my application.

My question is regarding magnitude of Output selected by select lines.

Is Output voltage magnitude which is selected by select lines same as what we are assigning at input of MUX ( 8 pins )irrespective of VCC voltage of MUX((3.3v/5V)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When ...

a) the input voltage is within the range Vcc to Vee

b) there is no current being passed between the selected input and the output terminal (the switch has an on resistance of a few 10s of ohms)

c) you can neglect the very small amount of leakage current that appears in the switch (the data sheet gives a max of a few uA over the full temperature range, typically it will be much less, and much less again at 25C)

d) the select and enable logic lines are between GND and Vlow, or Vhigh and Vcc, where Vlow and Vhigh are the logic threshholds for the chosen Vcc (usually 0.8v and 2.0v for an HCT part, 0.3*Vcc and 0.7*Vcc for an HC part respectively). If the logic is between Vlow and Vhigh, the switches may not turn fully on, or several may turn on. If the voltage is outside GND and VCC, then extra leakage current may be injected into the switch.

then yes, the output voltage = the input voltage, regardless of Vcc.

Comment: (Thanks) Even irrespective of pull up voltage on select lines (3.3V/5V) considering above points which you mentioned?

Comment: @Electroholic I'll update the conditions in the answer to meet that question